# Using regular expressions with Python to extract floats between two given integers

Tags: regex, python-3.x

In my particular case, the upper bound on my search is always going to be a three-digit number and they will both be positive floats/integers. However, I can always appreciate a solution that works in general.

It seems to me that solving this requires first finding the length of our minimum number. I currently have something like:

```
# These are strings to make indexing easy
max_num = '120'
min_num = '110'

# I also check if the minmum number is 2 or 1 digits long and have special cases  
# for those but this is sufficient to show what the issue is
if len(min_height) == 3:
    regex = re.findall(
        r"[{}-{}][{}-{}][{}-{}].?\d*".format(min_num[0], max_num[0],
        min_num[1], max_num[1], min_num[2], max_num[2]), str(lines))
```

This fails in this particular case because the 'ones' place doesn't search from 0-9 as we need it to. However, if I make it generally search from 0-9 then it will fail when i have something like:

```
max_num = '123'
min_num = '112'
```

One easy solution would be to check the difference in the 'ones' and 'tens' places. However, I'm hoping to find a more elegant solution that doesn't rely on loads of 'if' statements.

Comment: Do you want to basically replicate http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is the kind of task I'm looking to do but I'm looking to create a single regular expression that is able to search between any two floats with the larger being three digits (if it is even possible). I guess one possible solution might be to find all the limiting cases given by that generator and just use the | to try each. However, I'm hoping for something a little cleaner (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solves your problem

```
import regex
def lng(no):
    '''to find out length of a +ve number'''
    length=0
    while(True):
        no=no//10
        length=length+1
        if no==0:
            break
    return length  
#u can set any +ve number including 0 in both maxno and minno
maxno=100
minno=20
pattern=regex.compile(r'\d{%d,%d}\.\d+'%(lng(minno),lng(maxno)))
string='3289032 884.399 99.99 29.1'
ans=regex.findall(pattern,string)
ans=[x for x in ans if float(x)<maxno and float(x)>minno]
print(ans)
```

Comment: I like this but I was hoping to find something that doesn't rely on list comprehension or anything like that; I'm searching for a particular regex pattern that, when used with findall(), returns only the numbers within the specified region (assuming what I'm asking is even possible).

Comment: oh sure!! i will try to figure it out that way.